# When and how many times a day do a clock’s hands overlap?

Tags: geometry

The time is 0:00.00. Hands are moving continuously. What is the next angle when they are meet again?
Answer for the 2nd question is 22 I think. And for the 1st question I think like this, but is cant solve.

HT = 30T,
MT = 360T,
ST = 360T × 60 = 21600T

MT - HT = 360 × n, 
ST - HT = 360 × m

360T - 30T = 330T = 360n
21600T - 30T = 21570T = 360m

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcqdqsQq-6M

Comment: in 12 hours - one hand is doing 12 rounds, the second one exactly one. So 11 times in 12 hours. And there is a rotational symmetry of the problem. So $\frac{2\pi}{11}$.

Comment: Thanks, and what is the first angle when the hour hand and the second hand meet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity sake, lets figure it out for  $12$ rather than $24$ hour period.

If $m$ is the number of minutes past noon, then the hour hand is at $360^\circ(\frac m{12*60})$ and the minute hand is at $360^\circ(\frac m{60}- \lfloor \frac m{60} \rfloor)$ where $0 \le m < 12*60$.

So $\frac {m}{12*60}  = \frac m{60}- \lfloor \frac m{60} \rfloor$

$\lfloor \frac m{60} \rfloor = \frac m{60}(1 - \frac 1{12})= \frac {11m}{12*60}$

For $0 \le m < 12*60$ there $12$ possible values for $\lfloor \frac m{60} \rfloor$.  They are $k = 0... 11$.

So $k = \frac {11m}{12*60}$

$m = \frac {12*60}{11}k$.

however note that for $k = 11$ then $m = 12*60$.

So the hands match up every $65 \frac 5{11} $ minutes and this occurs $12$ times is a $12$ hour period *IF* you consider that this occurs at $12$ noon and $12$ midnight.  In a $24$ hour period it will occur $23$ times.  Noon, midnight, and noon again, and other times each twelve hour period.

The angles will be $360^\circ(\frac m{12*60}) = \frac 12^\circ m = \frac 12^\circ\frac {12*60}{11}k = 360^\circ \frac {k}{11}$.

Comment: Thanks, and what is the first angle when the hour hand and the second hand meet?

Comment: What do you think $360^\circ \frac k{11}$ could be if $k = 1$?

Comment: Of course. But I asked only hour and second hand. I can solve this, 360 * (1/719).